# javascript on input field addition

Tags: javascript, html

```js
//// JavaScript function to add input values display into another input field 
function calculate() {
  var x = document.getElementById('fee_selector_holder').value;
  var y = document.getElementById('content').value;
  var result = document.getElementById('result');
  var myResult = x + y;
  result.value = myResult;

}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="hostelfees" id="content" oninput="calculate()">

<input type="text" name="fee_id" id="fee_selector_holder" oninput="calculate()">

<input type="text" id="result" name="totalfee">
```

I am giving values to input fields  its adding concatination but not adding please verify it  on input function is correct or wrong once verify then reply me thats it my question.

Comment: values are not added with addition symbol but its working with multiplu and subtraction division

Answer (score 1):

You have strings, that is why it is concatenating. Make integers with:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp

And it will work well.

Comment: and also i want check radio button changed dynamically input value then that value should be added to another input feild

Answer (score 1):

First, when you read values from DOM, they are read as string. You will have to use `parseInt` or `parseFloat`  to convert string to integer.

Second, `+` operator has a override function for string to act as concatenation operator.

Also notice, I have used `.value || 0`. Here if value does not exist, performing arithmetic operation over it will return `NaN` so adding default value (0).

```js
//// JavaScript function to add input values display into another input field 
function calculate() {
  var x = document.getElementById('fee_selector_holder').value || 0;
  var y = document.getElementById('content').value || 0;
  var result = document.getElementById('result');
  var myResult = parseInt(x) + parseInt(y);
  result.value = myResult;

}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="hostelfees" id="content" oninput="calculate()">

<input type="text" name="fee_id" id="fee_selector_holder" oninput="calculate()">

<input type="text" id="result" name="totalfee">
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to parse the input values to integer as all input values are string by default:

```js
//// JavaScript function to add input values display into another input field 
function calculate() {
  var x = document.getElementById('fee_selector_holder').value || 0; // default value 0 if input is blank
  var y = document.getElementById('content').value || 0; // default value 0 if input is blank
  var result = document.getElementById('result');
  var myResult = parseInt(x, 10) + parseInt(y, 10); // parse it here 
  result.value = myResult;

}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="hostelfees" id="content" oninput="calculate()">

<input type="text" name="fee_id" id="fee_selector_holder" oninput="calculate()">

<input type="text" id="result" name="totalfee">
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add attribute to `result`

```
result.setAttribute("value", myResult);
```